# How to put image in anchor tag dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have dynamically created image in javascript. I want img to be placed inside an anchor tag how can i do this?

```
        var element = document.createElement("img");
        element = cell.appendChild(element);
        element.setAttribute("src", "/Images/Delete.gif");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var anchor=document.createElement('a');
anchor.href='#';
var element = document.createElement("img");
element.setAttribute("src", "/Images/Delete.gif");
anchor.appendChild(element);
cell.appendChild(anchor);
```

i did not test the code, i used my brain as interpreter, so there may be an error in it. but i think you should get the concept.

Comment: Looks correct to me and actually answers the question if I read it correctly

Comment: But why so DOM correct? Why not just `cell.innerHTML += '<a href="#"><img src="..."></a>';` which does the exact same thing and is readable?

Comment: Because standards are a pretty cool guy, they are standartized and don't afraid of anything. If I recall correctly, innerHTML was invented by InternetExplorer. This should be reason enough, to not use it.

Answer (score 1):

element.setAttribute before you append it as you are redclaring element to what I presume to now be the cell... or don't assign element = cell.append..

```
var element = document.createElement("img");
element.setAttribute("src", "/Images/Delete.gif");
cell.appendChild(element);
```

What I suggest though would be:

```
function insertImage(anchorID, imagesrc){
  var img = "<img src='" + imagesrc + "' alt='image' />";
  $("#"+anchorID).html($("#"+anchorID).html() + img);
}
```

I am adding html within html in case there is any text in there you still want to keep.. otherwise negate that second statement of html

You need the jQuery javascript plugin for this to work.. http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

If you'd prefer not to include a plugin, then:

```
function insertImage(anchorID, imagesrc){
      var img = "<img src='" + imagesrc + "' alt='image' />";
      document.getElementById(anchorID).innerHtml = img;
    }
```

Comment: element = cell.appendChild(element); I said i wasn't sure tho.. is this returning the appended element? i'm not sure if you want to be assigning element to cell.appendChild

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a reference to the anchor tag (node). Let's say that's `a`. Since `A` and `IMG` are very simple html elements, this will work just fine:

```
a.innerHTML += '<img src="/Images/Delete.gif">';
```

Or if you want to replace the content of the `A` tag (instead of add the img), just remove the `+`:

```
a.innerHTML = '<img src="/Images/Delete.gif">';
```

Can't fail. In any browser. jQuery is overkill for something this simple (and would do the exact same underneath).

**edit**
But it looks you're inserting the `img` into a `cell` and not an anchor tag... Or your anchor tag is called `cell`? In that case, just replace `a.` with `cell.` =)